# How to get list of files that don't match patterns in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, find, regex

I have a file with joker character patterns:

> ./include/*
>
> ./src/*

etc.

From the current directory I would like to recursively get the list of files that **do not match these patterns**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
find . -type f \! \( -path '*/include/*' -o -path '*/src/*' \)
```

Breakdown:

- `\!` is negating the group
- `\( ... \)` is how to do groups of conditions for `find`
- `-o` ORs conditions
- Everything else should be self-explanatory.

If you have a new enough version of `find`, you could enhance it with:

```
find . -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex \! -path '.*/(include|src)/.*'
```

Comment: Chill out man, we are probably in different timezones... Thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: np, was just giving a friendly reminder =)

Comment: Dude. This response is excellent!

Answer (score 0):

First approach, but not using a list of files, others feel free to improve on that:

```
find . -type f -print | grep -v '.\/src\/*'
```